# The help center adventure continues (Proposed: slight tour change, help center change)

Tags: discussion, status-completed

> *(Continuation of [How can we improve our site tour?](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214/how-can-we-improve-our-site-tour))*

Our tour has been recently updated and it looks great! However, our [help center](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is less than ideal with its default template being applied.

**What it's like now:**

> Please [look around](/search) to see if your question
>   has been asked before. It’s also OK to ask and answer your own
>   question.
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for $SiteName, it may
>   be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently
>   exists that will accept your question, you may commit to or propose
>   a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/),
>   the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically
>   created.

How can we improve it? This post is to discuss any changes to that page.

Answer (score 4):

### Draft, feel free to comment/edit/vote on this.

Note that that `$SiteName` is automatically replaced in the help center and that a link or two might be broken here but it should work in the help center.

---

---

Welcome to $SiteName, our site about building communities of all types.  Like other Stack Exchange sites, ours is a question-and-answer site, not a discussion forum.  The kinds of questions that do best here are concrete, specific, and answerable.  To help keep the quality of our site high so people can get expert answers to their questions, please follow these guidelines.

To get good answers quickly, please **[make sure you know how to write a great question](/help/how-to-ask).**

Before you ask, please **[look around](/search)** to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to **[ask and answer your own question](/helpcenter/self-answer)** to share your wealth of knowledge.

Make sure that your question can be answered in a reasonable amount of time and it's based on facts and expertise, **not opinions.** Please see ***[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](/helpcenter/dont-ask)*** for more types of questions that generally don't work on Stack Exchange.

**Most questions that fall into these categories are on topic:**

- **Creating, expanding, and cultivating communities, their content, and the relationships among members.** This includes things like attracting new people with advertising, get more [contributions from members](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/950/how-and-when-do-i-attract-experts-to-a-young-site-that-doesnt-yet-have-much-exp), moderating your moderators, or just making your community grow as a whole.
- **Issues caused by members with different expectations, backgrounds, or tolerances.** We understand that people are different. As digital communities can have users from many different countries, issues will arise, such as [some people being offended by things that are acceptable in other countries.](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/587/one-persons-offensive-is-another-persons-meh-or-huh-how-do-i-media) Please note these issues often require specific details, so make sure to have plenty of details to get a good answer.
- **Questions about both online and offline communities.** We love talking about your book club or your nonprofit organization's growth in addition to your forum. Example: [How can I organically make sure that interested folks are included in volunteer tasks?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/879/how-can-i-organically-make-sure-that-interested-folks-are-included-in-volunteer)
- **Questions from both the leader's and user's perspective.** Many questions here are asked by community managers or moderators, but questions [from a member's perspective](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/924) are also welcome.

If your question is not specifically on-topic for $SiteName, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

**Don't ask about:** anything not directly related to building, administering, managing and cultivating communities. If yours is a digital community, **please avoid asking questions about a technical feature of your platform.**

Questions that don't meet these guidelines will probably be [put on hold](/help/closed-questions) until they can be edited.

Comment: Any wordsmiths: feel free to edit this to make it sound better! :)

Comment: Done!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

As I was drafting the help center revision, I noticed a minor detail missing from the *tour*. Should we fix this?

**Nothing is said about the user's perspective.** Suggestion:

> [...]is a question and answer site for community managers, administrators, leaders, moderators, and sociologists. [...]

**should be changed to:**

> [...]is a question and answer site for community managers, members, administrators, leaders, moderators, and sociologists. [...]

Comment: Also, it might be nice to mention something about how technology questions aren't allowed (we're getting a few of those but I don't know if they read the help center).

Comment: Done!!!!!!!!!!!